# Upgrading firebase from 8 to 9 not resolving data in promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I was using Firebase relatime database and was able to get data with `get` method and was able to return data using promise. Following is the snippet:

```
get(databaseRef: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.database
        .ref(databaseRef)
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          resolve(snapshot.val());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

Now we want to upgrade to Firebase version 9 and tried new syntax of firebase 9 to get data of realtime database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get. Following is the snippet:

```
get(databaseRef: string) {
    const data;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const result = onValue(ref(this.database, databaseRef), (snapshot) => {
        data = (snapshot.val()) || 'Anonymous';
        resolve(data);
      }, {
        onlyOnce: true
      });
    })
}
```

But with firebase 9 I am not able to get response from promise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {get, ref} from firebase/database;
const async getData = ()=>{
const reference = ref(yourreferencehere);
const data = await get(reference);
return data;
}
and then use getData method anywhere you want:
const data = getData();
```

Comment: I thank the problem is with sorting and filtring in the server. using orderByChild() equalTo() etc...